# Top tabs, bottom tabs and action bar tabs in android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-actionbar, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I am developing an android application which is the android version of existing iphone app.

In iPhone app, there are five bottom tabs (As iOS support these). Every tab has more than one activities.

**For example:**

Tab 1: It has activity 1 which starts activity 2 and so on with in the single tab (Tab 1) and also back navigation too.

I have already read following but still have doubts.

- http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html
- http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

**My questions are:**

1) What is the best replacement of such kind of tabs in android. If I use action bar tabs then It will the right approach?

2) If I use action bar tabs, then is it possible to start different activities with in the single tab and action bar back navigation too?

3) When I should use Action bar tabs, Top tabs or bottom tabs in android (Tab Host still not deprecated in the Android)

Please guide me. I am very confused about tabs in android.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use Navigation Tabs! (and With that probably you'll use Fragmnets and not Activity)

2) Of course, the Navigation Up is really an usefull thing

3) Bottom tabs is possible with a Custom Layout.. I think it's not best thing, but you can do it!

It's a very short anwser but you can check everything in developer training and checkin samples that you find in your SDK